# Frequent full garbage collection is occurring (~1.5 min), though old generation and meta space is not reached the maximum value

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

Environment :        java 8 with default garbage collector(parallelGC) not added any java flags, so it has taken 4gb as a heap memory.

when the garbage collection is happened following are the values for one instance but every instance with same approximate values full garbage collection is happening :

```
    when the old generation used memory is 500mb and committed memory 2.6 GB , Metaspace used memory is 107.060056mb and committed memory is 150.749184mb.
```

Following is the questions I have:

1.since GC is clearing the memory of old and Metaspace and young generation as well, I am assuming that is is full GC, is it correct?

2.I am tried figuring out why full GC is happening frequently since all memories are in normal state I failed to do it.

3.Since I am using java 8 didn't add any flags, I am assuming that collector is parallelGC, is it correct?. if it is so GC has to perform once any memory get's full but here it is acting completely different.

googled all over but never seen this behavior at all, so any other parameters that I have to look at than the parameters which I mentioned above (I got one -----JVM is triggering full GC whenever an internal application calls system.gc()  ) apart from this any other I want,  and references are much appreciated.

Comment: Please share your garbage collection logs. Start you program with the -verbose:gc flag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I got a solution for this problem. Because of the maximum metaspace problem full GC is occurring frequently.